# Is it safe to accept a new PGP key in pacman on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, security, authentication, key-authentication, pgp

When previously trying to install `arch-audit` on Arch Linux from the repository using `sudo pacman -S arch-audit` I was told:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) arch-audit-0.1.8-3

Total Installed Size: 1.89 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(1/1) checking keys in keyring [####################################################] 100%
downloading required keys...
error: key "D21461E3DFE2060D" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Now however when I try to install it I get this prompt:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) arch-audit-0.1.8-3

Total Installed Size:  1.89 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [######################] 100%
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP key 4096R/6DAF7B808F9DF25139620000D21461E3DFE2060D, "Christian Rebischke <chris@nullday.de>", created: 2015-07-16? [Y/n]
```

Where is the key in question being imported from? Is it definitely safe to accept it? Is the key being automatically downloaded from the official trusted servers or is it just coming with the package or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Rebische is a [Trusted User](https://www.archlinux.org/people/support-staff/#shibumi), the developers who maintain packages in the [community] repo and administer the AUR.

[arch-audit](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/arch-audit/) is packaged in [community].

You can check that Christian's key matches that as published on the staff page and then add it to your keyring.